# javascript syntax problem

Tags: javascript

I have this in the head of my document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var myString= location.href;
            var mySplit = myString.split("#");
            var x = mySplit[1];

            if (x == 'page1_div1') {
                document.getElementById('div1').className = 'theNewClass';
            }
</script>
```

What is my error?
Thanks,
Linda

Comment: What is the problem?  Is it not running?  Are the results not what you expect?  Do you get an error message?  Does your computer smoke?

Comment: Wouldn't the JavaScript error popup tell you what the error is?

Comment: >What is the problem? Is it not running? Are the results not what you expect?

I expect that the class of the div would change and it isn't changing. If it is 'theOldClass' and the URL has the hash of 'page1_div1' then I want to change the class of the div to 'theNewClass' .  I assumed that I had a syntax error since I am a newbie.

Comment: Try debugging the javascript using Firebug in Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the hash more easily through `location.hash` and since you will likely have several divs, it's easier to switch on them. Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myHash = location.hash || 'NO-HASH';

  switch (myHash) {
    case 'NO-HASH':
      // Original page - no hash.
      document.getElementById('div1').className = 'theOldClass';
      document.getElementById('div2').className = 'theOldClass';
      break;
    case '#page1_div1':
      document.getElementById('div1').className = 'theNewClass';
      document.getElementById('div2').className = 'theOldClass';
      break;
    case '#page1_div2':
      document.getElementById('div1').className = 'theOldClass';
      document.getElementById('div2').className = 'theNewClass';
      break;
  }
</script>
```

However, if this is related to your history tracking question, you'll want to run this code in a polling timer.

Comment: >if this is related to your history tracking question, you'll want to run this code in a polling timer.

It is a similar problem but not the same. The first question was between div's on the same page.  This question was about navigation between different pages. On the link to the first page, I am putting a hash that does not resolve on the linked page just to have some tracking between pages. Max, how to I go about hiring you to solve my javascript problems :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you have that code in the `head` of your document as you say, the problem is that `document.getElementById` is not able to find your `"div1"` element, because when it is executed, the `body` of your document hasn't been evaluated, try to use the `window.onload` event:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var x = location.hash.substring(1);

  if (x == 'page1_div1') {
    document.getElementById('div1').className = 'theNewClass';
  }
};
```

Note that I also simplified your code a little bit, you wanted to extract the `hash` part of the current url.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much especially for the explanation for why it was not finding div1.